# Problems with Kentico and Wildcard URLs after upgrade to 11

Tags: url-routing, wildcard, kentico

#### Foreword:

This question may be too specific for Stack Overflow.
I have also posted it on the Kentico forums: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/problems-with-kentico-and-wildcard-urls-after-upgrade-to-11

#### Synopsis:

After upgrading to Kentico 11, the wildcard setup I have no longer seems to be working properly. After a lot of digging and research, I think the problem is somewhere in the mechanism that Kentico uses to map the wildcard values to URL parameters... but I don't know how to look into that process to try and figure out where it's going wrong and/or how to fix it.

#### Details:

I have a page set up with the following "Standard URL or wildcard" value set:
`/Invest/Communities/{ProvinceName}/{EconomicRegionName}/{RegionalDistrictName}/{CommunityName}` This page also has a single alias of `/Invest/Communities/Province` but I'm not sure that's doing anything for me.
The page itself contains a single custom control, which has a User control virtual path of `~/<project>/WebControls/Communities/Community.ascx`

Prior to the upgrade, this URL: `/Invest/communities/myProvince/myEconomic/myRegional/myCommunity/` worked fine - if I set a breakpoint at the start of the `Community.ascx.cs` `Page_Load {}` method, the breakpoint would get hit, and I could pull those four values out of the query string (via e.g. `HttpContext.Current.Request["ProvinceName"]`).

After the upgrade, the same URL is not hitting the breakpoint, and is instead directing me to a 404 error. However, if I manually re-write the URL to `/invest/communities/profile/?ProvinceName=myProvince&EconomicRegionName=myEconomic&RegionalDistrictName=myRegional&CommunityName=myCommunity` the page works as expected. Breakpoint hit, values can be pulled from `Request` object.

It seems as though something has gone wrong with whatever mechanism does the value mapping... but as that's stuff built into Kentico, I'm not clear on how to look deeper into it to see where it's failing.

#### Other things I have tried:

- Re-signing all macros. This fixed a different problem I had after the upgrade, but did not help with this issue.
- On the Pages > URLs tab: changing from `Standard URL or wildcard` to `Route`
  Found this advice in a forum post somewhere; doing this made it so that I would hit the breakpoint in the control again properly, however none of the wildcard values were available in the `Request` object any more. Not good.
- 'Saving' on the page tab, the URLs tab, and other places in case somehow there was something corrupted that re-saving would somehow reset. Total shot in the dark, but in very rare cases this has worked before. No help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was actually a bug in Kentico 11.0.0.
I ended up contacting Kentico support, and they hotfixed it.

The bug is resolved by the Kentico 11.0.7 hotfix.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this, and seem to have found a workaround.

If I use your wildcard path in the page's URL path, I get your error.
However, if I use the wildcard path as a page alias, I can get at all the wildcard parameters.
https://www.screencast.com/t/jj2DesUrsGLR

Best,
Matt

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, when I try to add that alias, it tells me there's a collision and won't let me add it. I'm going to keep poking at it to see if I can figure out where it's colliding and fix that.

Comment: You may have already done this, but you probably need to remove the wildcard path from the URL path field before adding it as a page alias.

Comment: I did try that. There are actually a number of wildcard URLs in our app, and it turns out it was conflicting with a different one. I ended up remove the other one, for testing purposes, and I'm still having issues... I've reached out to Kentico Support - they've been able to reproduce it and they passed it on to the Dev team. So it sounds like it might be either a bug, or at the very least a change from K8.1. Anyway, thanks for your post, because it gave me some ideas that ultimately led me to discover enough stuff to let Support know what's happening.